# OpenGL ES2 color and texture shader

Tags: android, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

I want to write one vertex shader to work with colors and textures I used this code

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 v_Color;
uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit;
varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor= (v_Color*texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates));
}
```

it works when the model has a texture map but if the model has only color it loads black, I want to check the sampler2D `u_TextureUnit` before putting `gl_FragColor`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have written a shader that reads from a texture unit; you should generally avoid conditionality in shaders as it potentially splits the execution path. Usually a compiler can figure it out if the thing you're acting conditionally upon is a uniform but you may end up paying for a recompile every time you set the uniform. ES 2 has no means of introspecting the current properties of a sampling unit so the prima facie solution might be something like:

```
uniform bool u_ApplyTexture;
...
if(u_ApplyTexture)
    gl_FragColor = {what you already have};
else
    gl_FragColor = v_Color;
```

A non-conditional alternative possibly to profile as an alternative might be:

```
uniform float u_TextureWeight;
...
gl_FragColor = v_Color*
                   mix(vec4(1.0), 
                       texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates), 
                       u_TextureWeight);
```

As that would evaluate to `v_Color*vec4(1.0)` when `u_TextureWeight` is `0.0` and `v_Color*texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates)` when `u_TextureWeight` is `1.0`.

If you were really looking to be hacky, you might just upload your textures as negative images and negative them again in the shader:

```
gl_FragColor = v_Color*(vec4(1.0) - texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates));
```

As then obviously if you're getting `vec4(0.0)` from the sampling unit because no texture is attached, that ends up multiplying `v_Color` by `1.0`.

Comment: I'd stick with the first non-hackish solution :)  Or use two different shaders ...

Comment: Indeed. Most straightforward thing first, always. Add complexity only to the extent that performance dictates it to be necessary.